# Ubuntu based program wont compile

Tags: compiling

I am learning C language via "C For Dummies" and am writing a program for Ubuntu. I have written the program but cannot compile it. I installed a gcc, wrote the program and thought I was in the correct folder. The program is named Goodbye.c. The code is written as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf(Goodbye, cruel world!\n");
   return(0);
}
```

When I attempt to enter the command `gcc goodbye.c -o goodbye` I am given the message

```
gcc: error: goodbye.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the program to compile correctly in order for me to be able to run it?

Comment: Please re-read your question; you mention the file is named `Goodbye.c` but your compile refers to it as `goodbye.c`  which is a different filename (ie. G & g are different characters!)

Comment: Ok i have renamed the program goodbye.c now im getting error messages needing a semicolon before "return" and at the end of line 7. I have entered those but it still gives me those same errors. What next?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is case sensitive, unlike Windows. Therefore `goodbye.c` is different from `Goodbye.c`.

Also, if that is your exact code, you will get another error:

```
printf(Goodbye, cruel world!\n");
```

needs an opening quote; it should be

```
printf("Goodbye, cruel world!\n");
```

Comment: Ok i have renamed the program goodbye.c now im getting error messages needing a semicolon before "return" and at the end of line 7. I have entered those but it still gives me those same errors. What next?